# Batch program closes with Enter even if no option is selected

Tags: batch-file

I'm new to stackoverflow!

Straight to it:
PC / Windows 10 x64
Script level: Novice

I've written a basic batch program with selectable menu, however, if Enter is made with nothing from the menu, the batch program closes.
I'm looking for a simple script that will make Enter (with no selection) essentially do nothing, or return to the beginning of the batch program.

Thanks in advance.
Jon

```
    :mainmenu
@echo off
cls
color 1f
echo.
echo  =========================================================
echo  =        R U N   A S   A D M I N I S T R A T O R        =
echo  =========================================================
echo.
echo.
echo     WINDOWS COMMAND UTILITY (MAIN MENU):
echo     ------------------------------------
echo.
echo     [1] - BOOT COMMANDS
echo.
echo     [2] - WINDOWS HEALTH COMMANDS
echo.
echo     [0] - Exit Menu (Closes this window)
echo.
echo.
SET /P M=Enter option [Number] then press ENTER:
IF %M%==1 GOTO bootcommands
IF %M%==2 GOTO winhealth
IF %M%==0 GOTO exit
GOTO exit

:bootcommands
@echo off
cls
color 4e
echo.
echo  =========================================================
echo  =        R U N   A S   A D M I N I S T R A T O R        =
echo  =========================================================
echo.
echo.
echo     BOOT COMMANDS:
echo     --------------
echo.
echo     [1] - Windows (Normal Startup)
echo.
echo     [2] - Windows Safe Mode (Offline)
echo.
echo     [3] - Windows Safe Mode with Networking
echo.
powershell write-host -fore yellow -back red Tampering with the UEFI/Bios may render the PC unbootable!
echo     [8] - Boot into UEFI/Bios
echo.
echo     [0] - Return to MAIN MENU
echo.
echo.
SET /P M=Enter option [Number] then press ENTER:
IF %M%==1 GOTO normal
IF %M%==2 GOTO safe
IF %M%==3 GOTO safenetwork
If %M%==8 GOTO bootbios
IF %M%==0 GOTO mainmenu
GOTO exit

:normal
bcdedit /deletevalue {default} safeboot
goto reboot
exit

:safe
bcdedit /set {default} safeboot minimal
goto reboot
exit

:safenetwork
bcdedit /set {default} safeboot network
goto reboot
exit

:bootbios
shutdown /r /fw /f /t 2
exit

:reboot
shutdown /f /t 2

:winhealth
@echo off
cls
color 1f
echo.
echo  =========================================================
echo  =        R U N   A S   A D M I N I S T R A T O R        =
echo  =========================================================
echo.
echo.
echo     WINDOWS HEALTH COMMANDS:
echo     ------------------------
echo.
echo     [1] - *Create a System Restore Point
echo.
echo     [2] - Elevated Command Prompt (Administrator Privileges)
echo.
echo     [3] - SFC (Offline) File System Checker
echo.
echo     [4] - DISM CheckHealth (Offline) Deployment Image Servicing and Management
echo.
echo     [5] - DISM ScanHealth (Offline) Deployment Image Servicing and Management
echo.
powershell write-host -fore red -back yellow Option 6 requires Internet Connection!
echo     [6] - DISM RestoreHealth (Online) Deployment Image Servicing and Management
echo.
echo     [7] - CHKDSK (Offline) Check Disk checks the file system and file system
echo           metadata of a volume for logical and physical errors.
echo.
echo     [0] - Return to MAIN MENU
echo.
echo.
SET /P M=Enter option [Number] then press ENTER:
IF %M%==1 GOTO createrestore
IF %M%==2 GOTO cmdadmin
IF %M%==2 GOTO sfc
IF %M%==3 GOTO dismhealth
IF %M%==4 GOTO dismscan
IF %M%==5 GOTO dismrestore
IF %M%==6 GOTO chkdsk
IF %M%==0 GOTO mainmenu
GOTO exit

:createrestore
cls
echo.
echo Creating a System Resore point. Please be patient...
echo.
echo.
wmic.exe /Namespace:\\root\default Path SystemRestore Call CreateRestorePoint "Windows Command Utility", 100, 7
echo.
exit

:cmdadmin
start cmd /k
exit

:sfc
cls
echo.
echo Starting System File Checker. This is a utility in Microsoft Windows
echo that scans for and restores corrupted Windows system files. 
cmd /k sfc /scannow
exit

:dismhealth
cls
echo.
echo This is a quick scan and will determine if the image is repairable.
cmd /k DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /CheckHealth
exit

:dismscan
cls
echo.
echo This is a quick scan and will determine if there are any corruptions detected.
cmd /k DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /ScanHealth
exit

:dismrestore
cls
echo.
echo Your system will automatically connect to the Windows Update
echo service to download and replace the corrupt files.
cmd /k DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth
exit

:chkdsk
cmd /k chkdsk.exe /f /r /x
exit

:exit
exit
```

Comment: Simple fix, change your entire menu system, from using the wrong command, `Set` with its `/P` option, to the correct command utility, `choice.exe`, (designed to exactly this type of task.). Incidentally, please do not ask us to help you to fix a code problem, when not submitting your problem code. This is a technical site, not a guess and hope type of service. There is an [Edit] button available for you to submit your code, and the updated version using `%SystemRoot%\System32\choice.exe`.

Comment: Please provide your code. without it, we can only guess what your mistake is. I could guess your using `Set /p var=prompt description`, and I could guess your assessing the variable like `If %Var%==value command` - which will result in a syntax error if `var` is undefined, such as when a user presses enter with no input. If my guess at your mistake is correct, use `If "%var%"=="value" command` instead. Of course, this is all just a guess, because without your code, that's all we can do.

Comment: If `%M%` doesn't equal 1 or 2 or 0, then all three of those `if` statements get skipped and the line `goto exit` is executed, at which point the script goes to `:exit` and then runs the `exit` command, which makes it - you guessed it - exit the script. You want the script to go back to `:mainmenu` if none of the `if` statements get activated.

Comment: `SET /P "var=Prompt"` does not change `var` if [Enter] alone is pressed. Consequently, if `var` is originally empty, it remains empty. The result is that a statement like `If %M%==8 ` will be executed as `If ==8 ` which is a syntax error if `M` is empty. If `M` has been set by another menu entry. then [Enter] will re-choose that last entry.

Answer (score 0):

As per my comment, the fix is to use the correct command utility, `choice.exe`.

```bash
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

:mainmenu
    ClS
    Color 1F
    Echo=
    Echo  =========================================================
    Echo  =        R U N   A S   A D M I N I S T R A T O R        =
    Echo  =========================================================
    Echo=
    Echo=
    Echo     WINDOWS COMMAND UTILITY (MAIN MENU):
    Echo     ------------------------------------
    Echo=
    Echo     [1] - BOOT COMMANDS
    Echo=
    Echo     [2] - WINDOWS HEALTH COMMANDS
    Echo=
    Echo     [0] - Exit Menu (Closes this program)
    Echo=
    Echo=
    %SystemRoot%\System32\choice.exe /C 120 /N /M "Input option [Number]"
    If ErrorLevel 3 Exit /B
    If ErrorLevel 2 GoTo winhealth

:bootcommands
    ClS
    Color 4E
    Echo=
    Echo  =========================================================
    Echo  =        R U N   A S   A D M I N I S T R A T O R        =
    Echo  =========================================================
    Echo=
    Echo=
    Echo     BOOT COMMANDS:
    Echo     --------------
    Echo=
    Echo     [1] - Windows (Normal Startup)
    Echo=
    Echo     [2] - Windows Safe Mode (Offline)
    Echo=
    Echo     [3] - Windows Safe Mode with Networking
    Echo=
    %SystemRoot%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -NoP "Write-Host -Fore Yellow -Back Red 'Modifying the UEFI/BIOS may render the PC unbootable!'"
    Echo     [8] - Boot into UEFI/BIOS
    Echo=
    Echo     [0] - Return to MAIN MENU
    Echo=
    Echo=
    %SystemRoot%\System32\choice.exe /C 12380 /N /M "Input option [Number]"
    If ErrorLevel 5 GoTo mainmemu
    If ErrorLevel 4 GoTo bootbios
    If ErrorLevel 3 GoTo safenetwork
    If ErrorLevel 2 GoTo safe

:normal
    %SystemRoot%\System32\bcdedit.exe /deletevalue {default} safeboot
    goto reboot
    
:safe
    %SystemRoot%\System32\bcdedit.exe /set {default} safeboot minimal
    goto reboot
    
:safenetwork
    %SystemRoot%\System32\bcdedit.exe /set {default} safeboot network
    goto reboot
    
:bootbios
    %SystemRoot%\System32\shutdown.exe /r /fw
    Exit /B
    
:reboot
    %SystemRoot%\System32\shutdown.exe /r
    Exit /B
    
:winhealth
    ClS
    Color 1F
    Echo=
    Echo  =========================================================
    Echo  =        R U N   A S   A D M I N I S T R A T O R        =
    Echo  =========================================================
    Echo=
    Echo=
    Echo     WINDOWS HEALTH COMMANDS:
    Echo     ------------------------
    Echo=
    Echo     [1] - Create a System Restore Point
    Echo=
    Echo     [2] - Elevated Command Prompt (Administrator Privileges)
    Echo=
    Echo     [3] - SFC (Offline) File System Checker
    Echo=
    Echo     [4] - DISM CheckHealth (Offline) Deployment Image Servicing and Management
    Echo=
    Echo     [5] - DISM ScanHealth (Offline) Deployment Image Servicing and Management
    Echo=
    %SystemRoot%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -NoP "Write-Host -Fore Red -Back Yellow 'Option 6 requires an internet connection!'"
    Echo     [6] - DISM RestoreHealth (Online) Deployment Image Servicing and Management
    Echo=
    Echo     [7] - CHKDSK (Offline) Check Disk checks the file system and file system
    Echo           metadata of a volume for logical and physical errors.
    Echo=
    Echo     [0] - Return to MAIN MENU
    Echo=
    Echo=
    %SystemRoot%\System32\choice.exe /C 12345670 /N /M "Input option [Number]"
    If ErrorLevel 8 GoTo mainmenu
    If ErrorLevel 7 GoTo chkdsk
    If ErrorLevel 6 GoTo dismrestore
    If ErrorLevel 5 GoTo dismscan
    If ErrorLevel 4 GoTo dismhealth
    If ErrorLevel 3 GoTo sfc
    If ErrorLevel 2 GoTo cmdadmin

:createrestore
    Rem Rest of your code, irrelevant to your question, goes here.
```